# Why my list view doesn't scroll in android?

Tags: android, xml, listview

I have a list view when I populated it with data it doesn't scroll. Why is this happening I think there's no problem with my java code. I think the problem is with my xml. **Here's my xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg_main"
tools:context=".IreportMain" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="83dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_nav"
    android:gravity="top" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/Logo1"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/img_lamp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_greetings"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="Welcome Guest"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_Date"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="July 2, 2013"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_Logout"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:text="@string/logout"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:background="@drawable/selector_button_background"
            android:textSize="15sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

<ScrollView 
android:layout_below="@+id/header"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/Scrollview">

   <RelativeLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

   <RelativeLayout 
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
   android:id="@+id/header2" 
   android:layout_marginBottom="20dp">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/btn_iScan"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:src="@drawable/img_ireport_logo" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_Report"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btn_iScan"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="@string/report"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textStyle="bold" 
    android:textSize="20sp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_Code"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv_Report"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/row1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:layout_below="@+id/header2" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_Brand"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/brand"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_InformationType"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/information"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/row2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/row1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+DropDownList/tv_SubBrand"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="@string/select_brand" 
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="13sp" />


</RelativeLayout>

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spn_InfoType"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient"
    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    android:textSize="13sp" />

<!-- 
 <RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+DropDownList/tv_InformationType"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/select_informationtype" 
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
-->

</LinearLayout>

 <LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/row3"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/row2"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_District"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/district"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_CustomerSegment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/segment"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />


</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/row4"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/row3"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spn_District"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:textSize="13sp" />

  <RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout4"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+DropDownList/tv_ConsumerSegment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/select_consumersegment" 
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="13sp" />

</RelativeLayout>



</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/row5"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/row4"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_Province"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/province"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_DateObserved"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/observed"
        android:textColor="@color/black"/>

</LinearLayout>



<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/row6"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/row5"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spn_Province"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:textSize="13sp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" 
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="7dp">

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/chk_Competitor"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:button="@drawable/selector_checkbox"
            android:checked="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:text="@string/competitor"
            android:textColor="@color/black" 
            android:textSize="14sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txt_Date"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:ems="10"
            android:background="@drawable/edittext_bg"
            android:editable="false"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:textSize="13sp" />


        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/row9"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/row6"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_Remarks"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:text="@string/remarks" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/row10"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/row9"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txt_Remarks"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/edittext_bg"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="top|left"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:lines="3"
        android:paddingLeft="3dp"
        android:scrollHorizontally="false"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:textSize="13sp" />

    </LinearLayout>



<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/row11"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/row10"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="5dp">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_AttachedFiles"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:text="@string/attach" 
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="16sp"/>
 </LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/row12"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/row11"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="5dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_File"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:text="@string/file" 
        android:gravity="center"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_Description"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:text="@string/description" 
        android:singleLine="false"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_UploadedBy"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:text="@string/uploadedby"
        android:singleLine="false" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_DateUploaded"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:text="@string/dateuploaded"
        android:singleLine="false" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_Action"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:text="@string/action" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/row13"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/row12"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="5dp">
    <!-- MYLISTVIEW THAT DOESN'T SCROLL -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv_AttachedFileData"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="147dp"
        android:background="@drawable/frame_white_1"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
        android:lines="3"
        android:padding="10dp" >

    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/row14"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/row13"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="5dp">

    <Button
           android:id="@+id/btn_Save"
           android:layout_width="70dp"
           android:layout_height="35dp"
           android:text="@string/save"
           android:background="@drawable/selector_button_background"
           android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
           android:textSize="15sp" />

    <Button
           android:id="@+id/btn_Submit"
           android:layout_width="70dp"
           android:layout_height="35dp"
           android:text="@string/submit"
           android:background="@drawable/selector_button_background"
           android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
           android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
           android:textSize="15sp" />

    <Button
           android:id="@+id/btn_Cancel"
           android:layout_width="70dp"
           android:layout_height="35dp"
           android:text="@string/cancel"
           android:background="@drawable/selector_button_background"
           android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
           android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
           android:textSize="15sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_Attach"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
        android:text="@string/attach"
        android:background="@drawable/selector_button_background"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/footer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_nav" 
    android:layout_below="@+id/row14"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/row15"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="5dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_help"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:text="@string/help"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_ContactUs"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:text="@string/contactus"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_Copyright"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/copyright"
        android:textColor="@color/black" 
        android:layout_below="@+id/row15"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_Reserved"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/reserved"
        android:textColor="@color/black" 
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_Copyright"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_Createdby"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_Reserved"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/createdby"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />
</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Any idea will be a great help thanks**

Answer (score 3):

Simply remove the `<ScrollView>`.A **listview** cannot work within a `<ScrollView>`

Answer (score 0):

Your ListView parent is ScrollView. So it loss scrolling property. So please remove ScrollView from this xml and after than run it's work fine.

It's better to set diffrent view type inside the ListView Adapter or use the ListView Footer and Header.

**Another Way to manage ScrollView inside ListView in android**

Also you can use this Method which will fix the issue you are facing with ListView in ScrollView

public static void updateListViewHeight(ListView myListView) {

```
 ListAdapter myListAdapter = myListView.getAdapter();
 if (myListAdapter == null) {            
          return;
 }
//get listview height
int totalHeight = 0;
int adapterCount = myListAdapter.getCount()
for (int size = 0; size < adapterCount ; size++) {
    View listItem = myListAdapter.getView(size, null, myListView);
    listItem.measure(0, 0);
    totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
}
//Change Height of ListView 
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = myListView.getLayoutParams();
params.height = totalHeight + (myListView.getDividerHeight() * (adapterCount - 1));
myListView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

}

Answer (score -2):

I know I'm posting this 2 years after the OP but it might help someone coming across the same problem.  I had this problem before and I fixed it using the following in my xml:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lv_LVID"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout:weight="1">

</ListView>
```

If it still doesn't scroll, try removing any `<ScrollView>` which you might have as an outer layout.